# Add a char padding in C strings

Tags: arrays, c, string

I am trying to implement this simple encryption method for a a list of numbers, the encryption is like this:
we add the 1st element of the list before every element of the entire list of numbers,
if we have:

```
   char array = "356307042441013"
```

the first number is 3, that means we need to add it before every element of the list of numbers:

```
  '33 35 36 33 30 37 30 34 32 34 34  31 30 31 33'

  char result= "333536333037303432343431303133"
```

is there any function in C that will make the implementation easier ? because I tried doing it with  shifting but couldn't get that result.

Comment: There is no such a standard C function.

Comment: No standard function does that, but it is a matter of a simple loop. [Well, in fact you could use a conversion function from char to wchar_t, then overwrite every other byte, but that would be stupid.]

Comment: By the way, this "encryption" method is immediately deciphered by a human.

Comment: Yeah, It is use to send a  connection inititialization to a server, it is used like this in major telecommunications companies to send data from embedded devices to servers, and I am trying to use it in one of my applications.

Comment: I guess the easiest way could be adding space padding between all the elements and then  changing every space with the 1st element.

Comment: @Othmane This does not make a sense. Why do not add at once the required character instead spaces?

Comment: yeah, you are right, I found a way to that.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't mix up a string representation of a number and the array of ASCII hex codes of the same? For example, the character `'5'` is coded in ASCII as 0x35 and might be presented by "35" without the hex prefix. -- This is not encryption, this is encoding.

Comment: Actually the 15 length number is the IMEI = International Mobile Equipment Identity, it is an actual number. and it had to be sent as a string buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do following:

**Step I**: Allocate memory of double the size of input and  `+ 1` to accommodate the null character to the result string.
**Step II**: Iterate through the input string and, in every iteration, first copy the `input[0]` character to current location of result string and, in very next location of result string, copy the current processing character of `input` string.
**Step III**: Once the loop exits, add null character at the end of result string.
[Take special care of empty string because it will have nothing to encrypt]

Implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * encryption (const char * input) {
    if ((!input) || (*input == '\0')) {
        return NULL;
    }

    size_t len = strlen (input);
    char * temp = malloc ((len * 2) + 1);
    if (!temp) {
        printf ("Failed to allocate memory\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    size_t i = 0, j = 0;
    for (; input[j]; ++j) {
        temp[i++] = input[0];
        temp[i++] = input[j];
    }

    temp[i] = '\0';
    return temp;
}

int main (void) {
    char array[] = "356307042441013";

    char * result = encryption (array);

    if (result) {
        printf ("result : %s\n", result);
        // Free the dynamically allocated memory once done with it
        free (result);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
result : 333536333037303432343431303133
```

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner, more concise solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char foo[] = "356307042441013"; 
    char bar[2 * sizeof(foo) - 1];
    char *src = foo, *dest = bar;

    while (*src) {
        *dest++ = foo[0];
        *dest++ = *src++;
    }
    *dest = *src;
    printf("foo=%s\n",foo);
    printf("bar=%s\n",bar);

    return 0;
}
```

It is better to use `foo[]` rather than hard-coding the length, because what if you want to change the string. If you use `[]` (empty brackets) the compiler will allocate exactly how many bytes you need (including the terminating null). Similarly, for `bar` we base the size on the size of `foo` by doubling it and subtracting 1 (since the terminating null does not need to be doubled).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this:

```
 int main() {
 char foo[16] = "356307042441013"; 
 char bar[2*16-1];
 for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
 bar[2*i] = foo[i];
 if (i != 16 - 1)
    bar[2*i + 1] = foo[0];
  }
 char res[32]= "3";
 strcat(res,bar);
 res[30] = '\0';
 printf("bar=%s\r\n",bar);
 printf("begin=%s\r\n",res);

 return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Isn't the `foo[0]` precede every character?

Comment: yeah, but adding it as a padding between elements is the easiest way to do so.